# how to get javascript Current Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

How can I get current date and hour like this 2020-07-06T12:30:00.

in JavaScript / react

can you help me?

Comment: You can use appropriate date formators to achieve this. Its pretty easier just search for date formators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use builtin `Date` object in JS.

```
const today = new Date()

let day = today.getDay()

let month = today.getMonth()

let year = today.getFullYear()

console.log(`${year}-${day}-${month}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date()` to access the built in JS date, and to access it the way you are specifying you want the `new Date().toJSON()` which will give you `"2020-07-06T20:25:23.671Z"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin `Date` object.

```
new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toJSON like

```
new Date().toJSON()
```